# Do HTTP POST Request Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script

I have a google script which submits form from external site information to my spreadsheet. My problem is when I test it on 4 device, and simultaneously run the function, it takes too long to respond. I have noticed that the request are processed 1 by 1. I am using this Google Apps script:

```js
var sheetName = 'Mulawin'

var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup() {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
    lock.tryLock(10000)

    try {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

        var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
            return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
        })

        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                'result': 'success',
                'row': nextRow
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    } catch (e) {
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                'result': 'error',
                'error': e
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    } finally {
        lock.releaseLock()
    }
}
```

and putting this code onto my html for the request.

```html
<script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbym9r2wztZLP49XORY-RRiDJpNVQtlpHJ8nbHDWf8iSpLnLN1GhcyJeu9I7gCxKfsnwqQ/exec'
    const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let retries = 2;
        const pause = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        const go = () => {
            if (retries--) {
                fetch(scriptURL, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: new FormData(form)
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        document.getElementById("pasakay-form").reset();
                        window.location.href = 'https://digitsorani.net/mulawin-pasahero-success/';
                    })
                    .catch(() => pause(500).then(go)) // pause half a second
            } else {
                alert("....");
            }
        };
        go();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: well, do the requests all at once - hope that helps - oh, wait, it's 4 different devices - not sure how your (lack of) code can fix that

Comment: Yes sir, i have noticed that the response from the spreadsheet is the main problem. Is it possible to bypass the response?

Comment: I don't understand, the request is coming from 4 different devices simultaneously - is the question about code on **your** server perhaps?

Comment: My script submits form to the googlesheet by means of fetch. I have anticipated that there will be instances that 2 or more device will submit form at the same time.

Comment: You need to show code and try to make the question more clear with more details.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. We can't help you without your code and more details.

Comment: already editted

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: is it possible to make a request simultaneously on different device?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lock on your script in the `doPost` function of 10 seconds. That will make it very slow. Imagine that you make the request from 4 different devices at ***"the same time"*** (which is unrealistic); then the last request that came to the script will at best be ready in 40 seconds.

You can alleviate this by perhaps showing a "processing" dialog on the client side so that users know that their request is being processed. Another thing you can do is probably reduce that time that the script is locked.